# Scripting/ import image from files to shading Image Texture

Tags: scripting, shaders

After 10 hours of research I'm finaly asking for help
I try to open an image from my files with a script here [image]

Until now I managed to create the image Texture and to set inputs and outputs
but I can't figure how to open my image

Here is my code for now

[image]

As you can see I'm a beginer, the answer is probably not as hard as I think

thank you

Comment: Why did you edit the formatting by the image adder? Hang on, I’ll fix it.

Comment: I’ve got some code that does this over on my GitHub, along with a lot of other node hookup stuff. https://github.com/thelabcat/SMD-Model-PostImport/blob/main/SMD_material_setup.py I think what you’re looking for is lines 118 and 119. Will explain in more detail if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked after adding lane 119 !

Comment: My goal is to create a script who import an image texture from a file, apply it to my object and save the result in a new one ( I want to repeat the task for 50 diferents images )

Answer (score 0):

````
#use first materal on selected objec
name_object = [obj.name for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects][0]
main_object = bpy.data.objects[name_object]
materal = main_object.data.materials[0]


# Get materal nodes(list) and BSDF, and LINKS 
materal.use_nodes = True
nodes = materal.node_tree.nodes
principled_bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF")
links = materal.node_tree.links

# Search for image
path = Path(search_dir)
for paths in path.rglob('*eye*layer1*'):
    if 'lod' not in paths.name:
        texture_path = str(paths.resolve())

if os.path.exists(texture_path):
    #Create texture, then node link texture to node
    image = bpy.data.images.load(texture_path)
    texture = bpy.data.textures.new(name="Texture", type='IMAGE')
    texture.image = image
    texture_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeTexImage")
    texture_node.image = image
    
    # link two nodes
    links.new(texture_node.outputs["Color"], principled_bsdf.inputs["Base Color"])

for index in nodes:
    print(index)
```
````

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners, code only, and tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how the code it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.